# linking a shared library fails after switching to clang with error adding symbols: file format not recognized

Tags: c++, building

The library is built from source but links against some stuff built with gcc (such as opencv).

The library is a .a file and I am on linux.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong? This was building fine with gcc.

I built clang-14, lld and clang++ from source. I installed clang-14 but can't seem to install clang++.

The linker used is ld 9.0 (I'm not sure how to make my cmake project use lld).

Comment: "can't seem to install clang++" is not a useful problem description. It can be inferred that there is a problem, but of what kind, nobody has any idea.

Comment: clang-14 is bleeding edge. Do you really need this specific version? If yes, you will need to show in *very* minute detail how exactly you build it and what exact error messages you get from what commands.

Answer (score -1):

gcc and clang are not compatible. Rebuild your library using clang.

Comment: This is as wrong as it gets.

Comment: They are not ABI compatible in some way. You must make sure you have two close version compilers, and hopefully they are ABI compatible, which they try to @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Comment: They are 100% ABI compatible. Not hopefully, it's a fact. Older C++ libraries are ABI-incompatible with newer ones, and libc++ is incompatible with libstdc++, but this has nothing to do whatsoever with file formats being not recognised by the linker.